# OpenTelemetry Collector Data not being fetched by Prometheus in Grafana

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, aks

I have a requirement where I have some container workload in Azure AKS cluster and I need to use OpenTelemetry to gather data like metrics, logs and traces. I also have Grafana as the visualisation tool and Prometheus as the data source. I need to use OpenTelemetry collector operator to get the data from the container workloads and use exporters, receivers and processors to push data to Prometheus and visualise data using Grafana. (Reference: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/tree/main/cmd/otel-allocator)

The following is the Kubernetes manifest for the OpenTelemetry collector:

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: otel-collector
  namespace: otel
spec:
  config: |
    exporters:
      prometheus:
        enable_open_metrics: true
        endpoint: '0.0.0.0:9464'
        resource_to_telemetry_conversion:
          enabled: true

    processors:
      batch:
        send_batch_size: 10000
        timeout: 10s

    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
            endpoint: '0.0.0.0:4317'
          http:
            cors:
              allowed_origins:
              - http://*
              - https://*
            endpoint: '0.0.0.0:4318'

    service:
      pipelines:
        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          exporters: [prometheus]
          processors: [batch]
```

After deploying the collector, a pod gets created as part of the operator. Once I try to get the logs of the collector pod, I am getting the below:

> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.517Z        info    service@v0.86.0/telemetry.go:84 Setting up own telemetry...
> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.517Z        info
> service@v0.86.0/telemetry.go:201        Serving Prometheus metrics
> {"address": ":8888", "level": "Basic"}
> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.518Z        info    service@v0.86.0/service.go:138
> Starting otelcol...     {"Version": "0.86.0", "NumCPU": 2}
> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.518Z        info    extensions/extensions.go:31
> Starting extensions...
> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.518Z        warn    internal@v0.86.0/warning.go:40
> Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network
> interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks
> {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus",
> "documentation":
> "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks"}
> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.518Z        warn    internal@v0.86.0/warning.go:40
> Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network
> interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks
> {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "metrics",
> "documentation":
> "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks"}
> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.518Z        info
> otlpreceiver@v0.86.0/otlp.go:83 Starting GRPC server    {"kind":
> "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "metrics", "endpoint":
> "0.0.0.0:4317"}
> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.518Z        warn    internal@v0.86.0/warning.go:40
> Using the 0.0.0.0 address exposes this server to every network
> interface, which may facilitate Denial of Service attacks
> {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "metrics",
> "documentation":
> "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/docs/security-best-practices.md#safeguards-against-denial-of-service-attacks"}
> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.518Z        info
> otlpreceiver@v0.86.0/otlp.go:101        Starting HTTP server
> {"kind": "receiver", "name": "otlp", "data_type": "metrics",
> "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:4318"}
> 2023-10-17T22:26:08.518Z        info    service@v0.86.0/service.go:161
> Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.

However, when I look into Grafana, nothing shows up.

[image]

I assume that metric data such as `otelcol_process_cpu_seconds`, `otelcol_process_memory_rss`, `otelcol_exporter_sent_spans`, etc should be listed. Am I missing anything here? Can someone please provide a clarity?